# How to get Clusters from ClusterManager Google Maps V2 in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to generate the a tree of clusters e.g At zoom level 6 I want to know that how many clusters are currently in the map and number of markers they contain. Is there any way to get the clusters from ClusterManager and the number of markers? Please help me .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at following GitHub code:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java